# NullReferenceException was unhandled in C# Timer TweetSharp

Tags: c#, twitter, timer, tweetsharp

I am working on a twitter project that lets user to auto-tweet to the mentioned tweets using C#. I am using TweetSharp with C#. The problem is, when I try to refresh the form_load that shows the mentioned tweets using timer, I get NullReferenceException was unhandled error. I tried change the time interval from 20seconds to 40seconds just in case if the problem is with the time interval, but the problem still existed, hence I don't think the problem is with the time interval. If anyone can help me with this problem I will really appreciate.

Below is when to refresh the Form1_Load:

```
        var timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
        timer.Interval = 20000; //40 seconds
        timer.Start();
```

This is where I get the error:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // form load bolumu
    {

        listView1.Items.Clear();
        tweetid.Items.Clear();
        userid.Items.Clear();
        username.Items.Clear();

        var received= service.ListTweetsMentioningMe(new ListTweetsMentioningMeOptions { Count = 15 });

        **foreach (var tweet in received)** --> This is where I get the error NullException
        {
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(tweet.Text);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            lvi.SubItems.Add("@" + tweet.User.ScreenName.ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add(tweet.CreatedDate.ToString());

            userid.Items.Add(tweet.User.Id.ToString());
            tweetid.Items.Add(tweet.Id.ToString());

        }
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across exactly this problem in the last week. I strongly suspect that it is related to access tokens expiring or other errors: I've regularly seen this occur after my program has been active for 5 minutes (of polling every 20 seconds).

I've added some code to check whether the return value is `null`, and just log a diagnostic message in that case, otherwise treating it the same way as an empty list. I have *once* seen it recover from this condition, but usually once it's started returning `null` it just continues doing so. I *suspect* (but haven't checked the source code) that somewhere there's code which is catching an exception and just returning `null` on any error (which is distinctly annoying, if it really is the cause).

This doesn't help you resolve the problem immediately of course - other than suggesting the same icky workaround I've used (treating `null` as empty and logging) but it's at least an indication that this isn't anything *you're* doing wrong - unless I'm doing the same thing wrong :)

EDIT: I've now looked through the TweetSharp code, and it looks like the interaction between TweetSharp and Hammock effectively masks exceptions, which is a great pity. So a return value of `null` doesn't necessarily indicate an access token issue - it's just "an error" :( It probably wouldn't be too hard to tweak the TweetSharp code base to throw exceptions appropriately instead... or it may be worth looking for an alternative API.

Comment: so basically there is no clear solution to this problem? if it is the case, then I will be in trouble :)

Comment: @user3185027: Not yet. I'm having a look at the source to track it down, but having just got back to my family after a week away, I may not get there today...

Comment: @user3185027: I've had a look through the code - see my edit.

Comment: @JonSkeet That means we should stop using TweetSharp

Comment: As i was facing this problem from past two days so i decided to switch to linqtotwitter. but i am facing problems in that too.

Comment: @FurquanKhan Maybe you could open a separate question on LINQ to Twitter. If there's a bug I can reproduce, I can fix it. Otherwise, it might just need an explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Check for null values before looping on the result:

```
var gelen = ts.ListTweetsOnHomeTimeline(new ListTweetsOnHomeTimelineOptions() { Count = 1 });
if (gelen != null) {
    foreach (var tweet in gelen)
    {
        //    s = tweet.Text;
    }
}
```