# GetRequestToken not able to access in WP7 twitterAPI Integration

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Guys this is the Error Message I am getting.

[image]

Picture take from [**Here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXsh5.jpg)

for `GetRequestToken` and `GetAccessToken` it shows that `TweetSharp.TwitterService` Class does not contain the definition

This Link I am Following to do This > [**Demo**](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/wp7-integrating-twitter-with-your-app/)

Comment: I would suggest you to stop using TweetSharp. Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21062493/nullreferenceexception-was-unhandled-in-c-sharp-timer-tweetsharp/21062562?noredirect=1#comment32220384_21062562 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138289/tweetsharp-getaccesstoken-method-returns-null-but-only-sometimes/21138290?noredirect=1#comment31848804_21138290

Comment: You can use linqtotwitter. i found it good